# how to pass a selection in a datagrid to show another datagrid

Tags: asp.net

I have two gridviews on a page
The first datagrid(requestgrid) is populated by using a stored procedure which has a parameter and that parameter is fed by the querystring.

The other grid in the page only needs to be displayed when i select a row in the first datagrid.Iam able to get the requestid from the selection using below code

```
void Requesttbl_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("clickrequestid"))
            {

                Requesttbl.Visible = false;
                int requestid = (int)e.CommandArgument;
               }
        }
```

My question is how do i use this requestid to pass it as a parameter to the second gridview

below code is my second grid view code in the markup page

```
<asp:GridView ID="SelectedReports" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="showselectedreports" EnableModelValidation="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Requestid" HeaderText="Requestid" 
                    SortExpression="Requestid" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="rptdesctext" HeaderText="rptdesctext" 
                    SortExpression="rptdesctext" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Completeddt" HeaderText="Completeddt" 
                    SortExpression="Completeddt" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Analyst" HeaderText="Analyst" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Analyst" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="showselectedreports" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UnderWritingConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="ShowCustomerSelectedRequests" 
            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
how do i use the requestid as a parameter here**strong text**
                           </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Bind the `SelectParameters` to a variable in your code behind class class and when you select something on the first grid, update that variable and call another `DataBind`?

Comment: Would you be able to help me in detail as iam very new and just dont know how to do on what you have suggested

Answer (score 0):

[image: ScreenShot]

This example might help you as i am getting value CountryID from one grid veiw and populating other on selected country ID, change according to your requirments.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="CountryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryID" HeaderText="CountryID" ReadOnly="True" 
                        SortExpression="CountryID" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [CountryID], [Country] FROM [Tbl_Country]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="CountryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryID" HeaderText="CountryID" ReadOnly="True" 
                        SortExpression="CountryID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" 
                        SortExpression="Country" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Country] WHERE ([CountryID] = @CountryID)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="CountryID" 
                        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Thank you much.I am trying to do same as what you have in your example.What code should i write in the event handler  onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: I am unable to pass the selected value in gridview1 to gridview2 and have the code similar as in your example